# take revenge on Vs enact revenge on

Tags: meaning

In an academic passage on story and storytelling, I've read:

> Brer Rabit uses his wits to enact playful revenge on his larger adversaries.

What is the difference if we say:

> Brer Rabit uses his wits to take playful revenge on his larger adversaries.

thanks.

Comment: Your version is idiomatic and correct; the original is a strained attempt to achieve academic pomposity which misuses the verb *enact*.

Comment: So, we have Ph.verb "enact on" ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. *Take* is the verb you want here; the *on* phrase is a complement of the noun *revenge*.

Comment: I thought revenge was sometimes *exacted*, not *enacted*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Brer Rabit uses his wits to enact playful revenge on his larger adversaries.

This is a malapropism. The correct and usual verb is 'to exact revenge'.

Unfortunately it seems that the error is not so rare.

[Google ngram: exact revenge,enact revenge,take revenge](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exact%20revenge%2Cenact%20revenge%2Ctake%20revenge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexact%20revenge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenact%20revenge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20revenge%3B%2Cc0)

You can see that, in published works, 'take' is most frequent, followed by 'exact' and then a small number use 'enact'.

Comment: +1 Hah! that hadn't occurred to me. A double malapropism!

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite, employing "take revenge", is the ordinary way of expressing this idea.

The original, employing "enact revenge", misuses the verb *enact*, which is correctly used in any of these senses:

- generally, to cause [a proposal or idea] to become "actual" or operative —*We are looking for means to enact the committee's suggestions.*
- more narrowly (and the most common use of the term), to cause [a bill] to become law —*Parliament enacted the Tea Act to shore up the financially troubled East India Company.*
- to perform [a role] on the stage or in another dramatic medium —*At Goodman's Fields, as afterwards at Drury Lane, Garrick enacted the role of Bayes in* The Rehearsal.

I would guess that the original was written by an author straining for academic elegance, perhaps with a vague misrecollection of the phrase ***act*** [one's] revenge, which was in use down to about the middle of the 19th century.

ADDED:
And even more likely, as chasly from UK suggests, with a misrecollection of ***exact*** revenge —which is itself a very loose use of *exact*, but one which has become acceptable through a century and a half of repetition.